# How To Open The Previous Form And Close The Current In C#?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, class, windows-forms-designer

I am working on a desktop app building on Windows Forms in C# on Visual Studio 2015 where I have too many forms that are attached among them using the below codes.

**First Form:**

```
using System;
namespace MyApps
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btnForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SecondForm openForm= new SecondForm();
            openForm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }  
    }
}
```

**Second Form:**

```
using System;
namespace MyApps
{
    public partial class SecondForm: Form
    {
        public SecondForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // +++++++++++ Need To Write The UPDATED Code Here +++++++++++
            MainForm openForm= new MainForm();
            openForm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        } 
    }
}
```

**Third Form:**

```
using System;
namespace MyApps
{
    public partial class ThirdForm: Form
    {
        public ThirdForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void btnForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SecondForm openForm= new SecondForm();
            openForm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }  
    }
}
```

So I am ok with the code to open the new form but I want the code to go back that should be general means if I open the `SecondForm` from `MainForm` then on clicking its back button, I should be on `MainForm` but if I open it from any other form like `ThirdForm` then on clicking the same button on `SecondForm`, I should be on `ThirdForm` so what code should I use on `SecondForm` back button?

Comment: In Program.cs you could create instances of all the forms and using a counter which is incremented/decremented on forward/back button click

Comment: You should raise an event so that the previous form knows to make itself visible again and close the next.  Writing a little controller class that uses `Stack<Form>` would be wise as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some form of state is required to remember what your last visited page was.

You could create a static class (or use `Program.cs`) that has a static member called something like `PreviousPage`. Every time you click a new form button, you update it appropiately.

Then a backbutton will hide whatever form it's on, and show the form reference in your static class.

```
public static class FormState
{
     public static Form PreviousPage;
}

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SecondForm openForm= new SecondForm();
        openForm.Show();
        this.Hide();
        FormState.PreviousPage = this;
    }  

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         FormState.PreviousPage.Show();
         this.Hide();
         FormState.PreviousPage = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is it what I want in simple. :-)

Comment: I answered this a long tme ago, while it works and is pretty simple to implement, I'd like to add that this is probably not a very maintainable way of doing this. If you want to learn about how to keep state in your forms application including stuff like backbuttons I would recommend reading about ways Microsoft themselves think you should do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the calling form as parameter in the constructor of the called form and store it in a private variable in the called form.

```
SecondForm openForm= new SecondForm(this)
```

In the back button click handler you can show the caller form again without creating a new instance. It looks like you are not managing object disposal this way though.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to accept FormType in constructor of Second Form

```
using System;
namespace MyApps
{
    public partial class SecondForm: Form
    {
        private string _formType;
        public SecondForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public SecondForm(string FormType):this()
       {
          _formType = FormType;
        }
        private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // +++++++++++ Need To Write The UPDATED Code Here +++++++++++
             if(string.IsNullorEmpty(_formType) || _formType.Equals("MainForm"))
          {
            MainForm openForm= new MainForm();
            openForm.Show();
            this.Hide();
           }
           else
           { 
              // code to open third form
           }
        } 
    }
}
```

Problem here is if you have too many forms calling second form then you may end up having if else or swtich cases. I think more elegant way woud be to pass Form itself in constuctor like below

```
using System;
    namespace MyApps
    {
        public partial class SecondForm: Form
        {
            private Form _previousForm;
            public SecondForm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            public SecondForm(Form form):this()
           {
              _previousForm = form;
            }
            private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


                                _previousForm.Show();
                this.Hide();

            } 
        }
    }
```

From Third or Main form you can just do this

```
 SecondForm form = new SecondForm(this);
     form.Show();
     this.Hide();
```

Comment: If you remember the type of each form you could just create an instance of the type instead of switching on its name.

Comment: @Glubus Yes..you can do that too but anyway what I gave was just one way of doing it but as I mentioned in my answer I prefer the second approach as it avoids switching based on form name and it also avoids reflection.

Comment: I know just thought it would be worth mentioning should he decide on this.